# PHP - Returning result from database and passing the value to another function

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class called TariffFareController, and I am getting the correct fare from the database as follows:-

```
class TariffFareController {

public static function getTourFare($fieldTour) {

       $pdo = new SQL();
       $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

       try {

           $query =   "SELECT Fare FROM tbltours
                       WHERE TourName = '$fieldTour'";

           $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

           $stmt->execute();

           $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

           $stmt->closeCursor();

           return $result;

           $dbh = null;

       }

       catch (PDOException $pe) {
           die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
       }

}

}
```

I then want to be able to check the result in my private get fare function:-

```
private static function getFare($int_terminate) {

    // $tour_fare = (the result from getTourFare)

        if ($tour_fare != null) {

            // do something

        }

        else {

        // do something else

        }

    }
```

How would I go about getting the $result from getTourFare and using this in the private getFare function?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Statements after `return $result;` don't get executed. You need to move `$dbh = null;` up or it won't be done.

Comment: I've removed that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both functions are in the same class, simply do

```
$tour_fare = self::getTourFare();
```

else you can call it from outside the class using

```
$tour_fare = TariffFareController::getTourFare();
```

Please notice that in the `getTourFare()` function the line `$dbh = null;` will **never** get executed 'cause you're returning from the function **before** executing it. I have also to say that I think that that line is quite useless cause the `$dbh` variable will go out of scope anyway.

Comment: `self::getTourFare();` comes up with errors as `$fieldTour` is a required parameter. I've changed this to `self::getTourFare($fieldTour);` then it shows an error as $fieldTour is undefined, any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I did not place parameters 'cause I supposed you knew how to handle them... If you have to call `getTourFare` from `getFare`, and `getTourFare` required a parameter `$fieldTour` then also `getFare` will need that parameter so to be able to pass it to the other function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some like this.

Call to getTourFare through getFare and if return data, do can process data instead return false you do any thing.

```
class TariffFareController {


private static function getFare() {
    if (self::getTourFare("any_field")) {
        /* Data success */
    } else {
        /* No data */
    }
}
public static function getTourFare($fieldTour) {

   $pdo = new SQL();
   $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

   try {

       $query =   "SELECT Fare FROM tbltours
                   WHERE TourName = '$fieldTour'";

       $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

       if (!$stmt->execute()) return false;

       if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
           $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

           $stmt->closeCursor();

           return $result;
       } else {
           return false;
       }

       $dbh = null;

   }

   catch (PDOException $pe) {
       die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
   }

}

}
```

Comment: I didn't think you could use $this-> within static content

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry.. don't see the static.